# Private static variable

Tags: c++, class, static

Why we have to declare static member function to access private static variable? Why not simply use a public function to access s_nValue? I mean why is it better to use static member function instead of a non-static public function?

```
class Something
{
  private:
  static int s_nValue;

};

int Something::s_nValue = 1; // initializer


int main()
{

}
```

Comment: Of course you can use a public member function to access (get or set) static member variables, even if the static member variable is private.

Comment: The question is not clear!

Comment: @Nawaz I read it on learncpp.com that its better to use static member function. I want to know is there any problem with a normal get_Value public function? Am I clear now?

Comment: @Jigyasa As I wrote in my answer, the "problem" is that you need an instance of the class if the method is non-static. If it's static you can just do `TypeName::Methodname();`

Comment: @Borgleader: I prefer to not use private static members in header files. I do not want them cluttered. Instead I put them .cpp file with internal linkage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why we have to declare static member function to access private static variable?

You don't have to:

```
class Something
{
  private:
  static int s_nValue;

  public:
  static int staticAccess() { return s_nValue; }
  int Access() { return s_nValue; }

};

int Something::s_nValue = 1; // initializer


int main()
{
    Something s;
    Something::staticAccess();
    s.Access();

    return 0;
}
```

Both methods work [as can bee seen here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=55d76fb38f95ead9d2dbd96dcd2db9e2-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)

That being said, it doesn't really make sense to make a non-static member function to access a static variable (as you would need an instance of the class to be able to call it).

Answer (score 2):

If you use pubilc function , you have to call it using an object, and it's not appropriate to call a static function with object, so better to keep it in static method which can be accessible directly through "classname::"

Answer (score 1):

> Why we have to declare static member function to access private static variable?

You don't have to. You can access a private static member from any member function, static or otherwise. You can also access it from any friend function, or member function of a friend class.

> Why not simply use a public function to access s_nValue?

Because that's *less* simple than a static function. You need an object to call a non-static member function; why not simply allow access to the static variable without creating an object?